# Setting expires header to multiple location block in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url-routing

In my `nginx` config, I have serveral location blocks, e.g.

```
location ~* /a { ..}
location ~* /b { ..}
location ~* /c { ..}
```

And I want to apply the `expires` header to all of above blocks, e.g.

```
location ~* ^/.*\.(?:css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ { 
    expires 1y;
}
```

Since in `nginx`, **location** blocks are **exclusive** to each other, so 
instead of repeating [1] the `expires` block in each of my locations above, are there better way to write the config?

[1]

```
location ~* /a {
    location ~* ^/.*\.(?:css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ ...
}

location ~* /b {
    location ~* ^/.*\.(?:css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ ...
}

location ~* /c {
    location ~* ^/.*\.(?:css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it for the `server` context instead of each `location`.

Then override, if you have any location blocks where it should not apply